# Wrong comparing of Double and Int numbers in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on calculator project but when I tried to use two similar ways of comparing double and int numbers I got different results.
So my question is Why are these ways of comparing works differently?

```
//some code that parse the string
//...
//code of calculating:

fun calculateIn(queueNumbers: Queue<Double>, queueActions: Queue<Char>) {
var action: Char
var result = queueNumbers.poll()
var operand: Double

while (!queueNumbers.isEmpty()) {
    operand = queueNumbers.poll()
    action = queueActions.poll()
    when (action) {
        '-' -> result -= operand
        '+' -> result += operand
        '*' -> result *= operand
        '/' -> result /= operand
        '%' -> result = result % operand * -1.0
    }
  }
  var pointNum = 8.3

  println("pointNum = " + pointNum)
  println(if(pointNum.compareTo(pointNum.toInt()) == 0) pointNum.toInt() else pointNum)

  println("result = " + result)
  println(if(result.compareTo(result.toInt()) == 0) result.toInt() else result)
}
```

Result of code:

```
"10.3 + -2" //input String

[10.3, -2.0] //queueNumbers

[+]//queueActions

pointNum = 8.3

8.3

result = 8.3

8
```

I think that is strange because if I run similar code I will get the correct result:

```
var pointNum = 8.3

println(if(pointNum.compareTo(pointNum.toInt()) == 0) pointNum.toInt() else pointNum)
```

So there is result of this code:

```
8.3
```

Full code on GitHub: https://github.com/Trilgon/LearningKotlin

Comment: `apply` returns the receiver. E.g. `3.apply { 4 } == 3`

Comment: Aside from your question, answered in the previous comment, you should know that Double is not suitable for a calculator because of precision loss. You should use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: Thanks, gpunto, now I figured out about apply but why is the second way (without apply) of comparing doesn't works like in second case?

Comment: I mean why `println(result.compareTo(result.toInt()))` returns 0?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this prints 1: `println(8.3.compareTo(8.3.toInt()))`

Comment: Yes it is but this one 

`println(result.compareTo(result.toInt()))` 
prints 0

Comment: What it prints depends on `result`'s value. What is it in your case? It will print 0 when `result = X.0`

Comment: Look at code in my question. In both cases it is 8.3 but when I use `println(result.compareTo(result.toInt()))` it will print 0 and when I use `println(pointNum.compareTo(pointNum.toInt()))` it will print 1

Comment: I have edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: To be honest I'm not entirely sure. Either it's a bug or I'm missing something very fundamental here ([playground](https://pl.kotl.in/hWyn6CihX))

Comment: It is sad but I tested my code in playground and get same result

Comment: @gpunto , I just published full code of project on GitHub. Maybe it will help: https://github.com/Trilgon/LearningKotlin

Comment: What I meant is that you're right and it doesn't work for me either. You should report it to JetBrains.

Comment: Okay I will. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a weird and even funny problem to me, But I think I found out what's the problem.

In Kotlin `Double` class is defined inside `Primitives.kt`, well at least in the [build-in files](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/af21b67eb5391439353ab5d0216de5f1eb36d681/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt#L1325) not in the actual source. Here `Double` class implements  an interface named `Comparable<Double>` which is another [built-in](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Comparable.kt) Kotlin file. You can see a portion of that interface:

```kotlin
public operator fun compareTo(other: T): Int
```

So let's return to your [code](https://github.com/Trilgon/LearningKotlin/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt). I suspend culprit of this problem is the very first line.

```java
import java.util.*
```

Inside the `java.util` package there is another `Comparable` interface, I think since `Queue` is a Java class and the `poll` method may return a nullable value, and since you already imported everything inside `java.util` package then `compareTo` is called from `Comparable` from `java.util` not the one in Kotlin package.

The reason why Java's `compareTo` returns a different result is unknown to me.

I tried replacing `java.util.*` with:

```kotlin
import java.util.Queue
import java.util.LinkedList
```

But nothing changed.

However, I found another solution, just [replace](https://github.com/Trilgon/LearningKotlin/blob/8273ff6e20072015b01a1b8ba3432b8e17728601/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt#L45) `var result = queueNumbers.poll()` with `var result = queueNumbers.poll() ?: 0.0` or `var result: Double = queueNumbers.poll()` then it would be fixed!

```kotlin
//original
var result = queueNumbers.poll()
//method 1
var result : Double = queueNumbers.poll()
//method 2
var result = queueNumbers.poll() ?: 0.0
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Looks like some problem with Kotlin compiler by the way

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a bug in the compiler. Discussion is [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/wrong-comparing-of-double-and-int-numbers-in-kotlin-bug-perhaps/24679), I copy my findings:

Minimal reproducible example:

```kotlin
fun test1(): Int {
    val d: Double?
    d = 8.3
    return d.compareTo(8) // 0
}

fun test2(): Int {
    val d: Double
    d = 8.3
    return d.compareTo(8) // 1
}
```

Technical difference between these two code samples is that the value is boxed in `test1()` and unboxed in `test2()`. If we look at the generated bytecode for `test2()`, everything looks as expected:

```
 7: bipush        8
 9: i2d
10: invokestatic  #63                 // Method java/lang/Double.compare:(DD)I
```

It converts integer value `8` to double and then compares both values as doubles.

But if we look into `test1()`, something bizarre happens there:

```
10: invokevirtual #52                 // Method java/lang/Double.doubleValue:()D
13: d2i
14: bipush        8
16: invokestatic  #58                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.compare:(II)I
```

It does the opposite: it converts double value `8.3` to integer and then compares values as integers. This is why it says values are the same.

What is interesting, even "Kotlin Bytecode" tool in IntelliJ shows the correct code for `test1()`:

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Double.doubleValue ()D
BIPUSH 8
I2D
INVOKESTATIC java/lang/Double.compare (DD)I
```

But the real generated bytecode is different and gives different results.

I reported the problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52163

Comment: I had some thoughts about problem with compiler but I wasn't sure how to check it. Thanks for your detailed answer and report for JetBrains.